# Before Create in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would like to setup a before_create for all of my modules

what i have been trying is:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module UserMonitor
    require 'securerandom'

    before_create :attach_uuid
      def attach_uuid
      self.uuid = SecureRandom.uuid.gsub("-","")
    end
  end
end
```

This does not seem to be working.
if i go into each module and add it in there it works,  but i want to do it on a global scale.

Any thoughts or ideas on how i can achieve this in this manner?  i know i could do it in triggers and such but i don't want to go that route and i would like to avoid hitting every module/class in case i need to change something.

Currently using Ruby 1.9.3  Can not currently upgrade my app until i make future code changes.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you see any error in the server log?

Comment: I am trying to run the server locally  here is where the error presets  when trying to run the server with those lines added to the usermonitor file


/home/userm/workspace/Applcation-O/vendor/plugins/usermonitor/lib/usermonitor.rb:5:in `<module:UserMonitor>': undefined method `before_create' for ActiveRecord::UserMonitor:Module (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define `attach_uuid` in the ActiveRecord module, can't you just call the `before_create :attach_uuid` at the top of each controller? This is DRY.

Is there a UserMonitor controller that you could add it to?

```
class UserMonitor < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :attach_uuid
end
```

Comment: Yes i could.  but i am looking to avoid adding that line to each controller if i can.

Comment: It's not DRY if *every* model in the app has the same line repeated.

Comment: I think re-defining `attach_uuid` in every module is repetitive, but calling it in each module seems necessary. The OP has moved most of the code to a common file.

Answer (score 2):

An other solution - I use, is to put the logic for UUID in an own module, that you include. I already have some (class-) methods I add to my AR, like `set_default_if`, so it was a good place for me.

```
module MyRecordExt
    def self.included base
        base.extend ClassMethods   # in my case some other stuff 
        base.before_create :attach_uuid # now add the UUID 
    end

    def attach_uuid
        begin
            self.uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
        rescue
            # do the "why dont we have a UUID filed?" here
        end
    end


    # some other things not needed for add_uuid
    module ClassMethods
        include MySpecialBase # just an eg.   

        def default_for_if(...)
            ...
        end
    end
end
```

and then

```
class Articel < ActiveRecord::Base
    include MyRecordExt
    ...
end
```

In general I avoid doing something for ALL models modifying AR base - I made the first bad experience with adding the UUID to all, and crashed with devise GEMs models ...